# Group content menu field in a View

Tags: group

I'm trying to display a group content menu on a view Drupal. Which field should I use ?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.